# How to cast this target using this form of inline destructuring in a input element on:input action using Svelte?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, svelte, svelte-3

I don't know how to cast this `target` here using this form of inline destructuring in a Svelte 3 form:

```
<input
  on:input={({ target: { value } }) => doSomething(value)}
/>
```

beacause typescript now is complaining with:

`Property 'value' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'`

I wanna assert `target` is an `HTMLInputElement`.

Am I wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`target` is the element where the event originated from. For bubbling events, this cannot be determined statically, therefore `target` is typed defensively (also see [this issue](https://github.com/sveltejs/language-tools/issues/579)). `currentTarget` however is typed as `HTMLInputElement` as you would expect.

```
<input
  on:input={({ currentTarget: { value } }) => doSomething(value)}
/>
```

Type-casting is currently not supported inside Svelte markup. The workaround is to declare a function in the script tag and do the transformation there.

```
<script lang="ts">
  function onInput(e: Event) {
    const target = e.target as HTMLInputElement;
    ..
  }
</script>

<input
  on:input={onInput}
/>
```